# opencv houghline vector error

Tags: opencv, vector

I am using OpenCV 2.4.3 with VS 2010. I tried compiling the example code for Houghline in VS2012 and it worked fine. But using VS2010+OpenCV 2.4.3 (because I wanted to use Qt), I receive the error

```
access violation reading memory location
```

I found out that it's because of the vector `vector<Vec4i> lines` when calling the program calls the function `HoughlineP(... , lines , ...)`, I looked online but couldn't find a clear solution to this problem. Could you please advice? thank you.

Edit:

```
vector<Vec4i> lines;
HoughLinesP(ROIcannied, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, intersect, 5, 5 );
```

Comment: post the full part of your code where you call the HoughP API..

Comment: posted above, is that sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your ROIcannied image is 8 bit and single channel binary. Note that Canny operator that you used gives an output image that is of the same type as its input. You should give a binary image to canny operator.